# datalist contol doesn't bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to bind the `datalist control` as per the values inserted in the form of find frined.
here is my code:

```
protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mahi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\fc 6-4\fc\App_Data\fc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

        cn.Open();

        string str = "select unm='" + funm_txt.Text  + "' , university='" + DDLuni.SelectedItem + "', city='"+ DDLcity .SelectedItem +"' , yjoin='" + DDLyjoin.SelectedValue + "' ,yleave= '" + DDLycom.SelectedValue + "', ybatch='" + DDLbtch.SelectedValue + "' from profile";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, cn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataList1 .DataSource =dt;
        DataList1.DataBind();
        cn.Close();

    }
```

Comment: have you debugged to see if "dt" is populated with some rows? If not, that might be the cause.

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: @nexus yes u r ryt dt is nt populated,.. wht should i hve to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things I have noticed:

-First of all, you are highly `vulnerable to sql-injection attacks` as you are passing user entered values directly into the database. You can `avoid this by using a parameterised query`.

-Secondly, you need to filter the records in a `WHERE` clause. At the moment you are assigning user typed/selected values into a select query.

-And you need to use `SelectedValue` of dropdown list not `SelectedItem`

-Also you can use `using()` blocks to get `SqlConnection and DataAdapter Disposed` at the end.

Try this (Please replace col1, col2 as required and complete the query assigning all parameters):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("your_conn_string"))
{
   string str = "Select Col1, Col2,... From profile " +
                "Where unm = @unm and university= @uni and " +
                "..." +
                "ybatch = @ybatch";

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, cnn);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unm",funm_txt.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uni",DDLuni.SelectedValue);
   ...
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ybatch",DDLbtch.SelectedValue);


   using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
   {
     adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

     cnn.Open();
     adapter.Fill(dt);
   }
}

DataList1.DataSource =dt;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    cn.Open();

    string str = "select unm='" + funm_txt.Text  + "' , university='" + DDLuni.SelectedItem + "', city='"+ DDLcity .SelectedItem +"' , yjoin='" + DDLyjoin.SelectedValue + "' ,yleave= '" + DDLycom.SelectedValue + "', ybatch='" + DDLbtch.SelectedValue + "' from profile";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, cn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.fill(dt);
    DataList1 .DataSource =dt;
    DataList1.DataBind();
    cn.Close();
```

Comment: Does data table any contain data?

Answer (score 0):

Add following code:

Your `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlCommand` is not communicating.

and you haven't filled `Datatable` with the result.

```
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.fill(dt);
```

Comment: what problem you are facing? please sue a breakpoint to check. then let me know.